# How to generate samples from joint distribution of normal and logistic with R?

Tags: r, logistic, random-generation, odds-ratio

How to generate triple data $(Y,R,X)$ with R code satisfying following restrictions:
$X \sim N(0,1)$, $R$ is binary and $P(r=1\mid y=0,x) = expit(\alpha_0+\alpha_1 x)$. $Y$ is continuous and $Y\mid r=1,x \sim N(\beta_0+\beta_1 x,1)$,$Y\mid r=0,x \sim N(\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\gamma ,1)$. Here $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1,\gamma$ are parameters.